# PHP received value from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog

I create Modal but I'd like to show count "dukung" from my database. 
I have a problem because, when I query like this >> "**select * from sekolah_dukung where kode='valuefromjavascript'**";

**this is my quote script**

```
var mycode = kode;
      <?php 
        $data_count = "select count(kode) as countkode from sekolah_dukung where kode='mycode'";
        $count = mysql_fetch_object($data_count);
        ?>
        h +='                       <b><?php echo $count->countkode ?></b>
```

**this is my full script**

```
<script>
function profile(kode,logo,alamat,ket,nama_sekolah,status_sekolah,orientasi_logo)
{
var ip = '<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>';
var mycode = kode;
var h ='';
h +='<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog" >';
h +='<div style="border:1px solid #369ace;">';
h +='       <a  onclick="remDialog()" title="Close" class="close">X</a><br/>';
h +='       <h2 style="border-radius: 25px; border: 2px ; padding: 10px;  background-color:#359ace; width: auto;"><center>'+nama_sekolah+'</center></h2>';
h +='           <div id="container2">';
h +='           <div id="container1">';
h +='                   <div id="col1">';
h +='                       <center><img  style=" padding: 5px 30px;"  width="160px" height="160px" src="images/sekolah/logo/'+logo+'">';
h +='                         <p>Klik Disini untuk mendukung agar sekolah ini menampilkan <br/> brosur online <br/></p>';
h +='                        <a href="#" id="dukung" style="cursor:pointer;"><button>Ayo Kami Dukung</button></a><br/>Jumlah yang mendukung <br/>';
<?php 
$data_count = "select count(kode) as countkode from sekolah_dukung where kode='mycode'";
$count = mysql_fetch_object($data_count);
?>
h +='                       <b><?php echo $count->countkode ?></b></center>';
h +='                   </div>';
h +='                   <div id="col2"><br/>';
h +='                       <p><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i> <font color="black">'+alamat+'</p><br/>';
h +='                       <p><i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i> <font color="black">0324242324</p>';             
h +='                       <br/><br/><br/><b>Keterangan :</b> <br/>'+ket+'';
h +='                   </div>';
h +='               </div>';
h +='           </div>';
h +='   </div>';
h +='</div>';
$('body').append(h);
$('#dukung').click(function() {
                kirimdukung(mycode,ip);
            });
}

function kirimdukung(mycode,ip)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'dukung.php?kode='+mycode+'&ip='+ip,  
                type: 'GET',
                success:function(result){
                            if  (result=="True")
                            {
                             alert('Terima Kasih Atas Dukungan Anda');
                            }
                            else if (result=="False") {
                             alert('Anda, Sudah Mendukung Sekolah Ini');
                            }   
                        }
            });
        }

function remDialog()
{
    $("#openModal").remove();
}   
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: i want show.. count/result from my database in my website

example : http://pastebin.com/6SXVHqpY

Comment: I dont think you can combine javascript and PHP like this.  PHP is server side code that is finished executing before the javascript even starts. the javascript does not have direct access to anything in the PHP code.

Comment: @lonewolf217 can you give me example..

Comment: Can you explain first why you are writing the entire modal code in javascript ? Why not write the modal in plain HTML/PHP, that way when the page loads it will have the value of the database call ready to show in the modal

Comment: i write modal in php
this my full script only put my code modal

Answer (score 0):

One problem here is that `mysql_fetch_object()` needs to be passed a query resource, so this should be:

```
$data_count = mysql_query("select count(kode) as countkode from sekolah_dukung where kode='mycode'");
$count = mysql_fetch_object($data_count);
```

However, have you opened a MySQL connection with `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_database()`? Otherwise, this won't work.

Additionally, as @lonewolf217 mentioned, this still won't work because `mycode` has no meaning in your PHP. The PHP is executed when you load the webpage, whereas the JavaScript is executed on the browser side. PHP has finished running long before your JavaScript executes.

Moreover, you should be using `mysqli` instead of the old mysql functions. Please read this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php Additionally, combining JavaScript and PHP in this way is very difficult to read and debug. I recommend picking up a recent book on PHP programming--or, better yet, JavaScript and webpage design--in order to learn these basics; it'll help you in the long term.

Comment: hey bro i know.. 
this full script only put code modal, i alreay include 
connection in my page..